# "Left over factors" of Fibonacci numbers squarefree?

Tags: nt.number-theory, square-free

One fact about Fibonacci numbers is they have the Mersenne-like property that $F_{mn}$ is divisible by $F_m$ and $F_n$ (but not necessarily $F_m F_n$, $F_3^2 \nmid F_9$ is a simple counterexample).  Of course, because Fibonacci numbers have exponential growth rates, $F_{mn}$ is much larger than $F_m$ and $F_n$ and has other factors.

If we consider the set of divisors of some positive integer $n$ (not including $n$ itself), we can generate several numbers which are divisors of $F_n$.  If we find the LCM of these numbers, we have a number comprised of all of the "Fibonacci factors" of $F_n$.  Dividing $F_n$ by this number we have a number comprised of the "left Over factors."  Let's call this number $O_n$.

With the exception of $O_6 = 4$ these numbers seem to be square free.  Are they?

A short python program and a sample run can be found at https://pastebin.com/iKjBq13C

Comment: $L$ is a bad choice in the context of Fibonacci numbers, because it's used for the Lucas numbers.

Comment: True, I will change it to $O$ for leftOver I suppose.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A061446](https://oeis.org/A061446).

Comment: Fibonacci-Wieferich primes?